# IronPython: Python.CreateEngine blocking on Windows 8

Tags: c#, python, windows-8, ironpython

I have an application that relies on IronPython 2.7.3.

I just switched to a new developement workstation with a Windows 8. Using VS2010 debugger, I clearly see that the function Python.CreateEngine never returns.

The app is a WCF Service Hosted in a Win32 Service using CmdLineService: https://cmdlineservice.codeplex.com/

In the Win32 Service start method, another thread is started to perform "heavy initialization".
This is where Python.CreateEngine is called. It locks internally when calling PythonFile.CreateConsole.

Anybody else experiencing this issue with Window 8 and IronPython?

Answer (score 0):

I tried to move the initialization of the engine outside of the "heavy initialization" thread and now everything works fine. Looks like, with Window 8, Python.CreateEngine must be called in the start method of a Win32 service, otherwise it locks.

Comment: Can you please create a bug report on https://ironpython.codeplex.com/WorkItem/Create, preferably with a minimal reproducible example? Running IronPython in a service is uncommon, so there might be some bugs there.

Comment: Did it: https://ironpython.codeplex.com/workitem/34020, I'll try to add a sample this week-end.